# how to make git smart http transport work on nginx?

Tags: nginx, http, git

I've tried this in many different ways. Here is probably the best configuration I've managed to come up with.

`nginx`:

```
server {
    server_name   git.domain.com;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/git.domain.com-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/git.domain.com-error.log;

    include common;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

        # fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
        # fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME   /1.pl;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/lib/git-core;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME   /git-http-backend;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;

        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL   "";
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO   $request_uri;
    }
}
```

I've written a little script to intercept data between `fcgiwrap` and `git-http-backend`. Here it is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
my $output = `/usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend`;
open my $fh, '>', '/home/yuri/git/1/1.txt';
print $fh $output;
print $fh Dumper {map {$_ => $ENV{$_}} 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_METHOD', 'CONTENT_TYPE', 'CONTENT_LENGTH', 'SCRIPT_NAME', 'REQUEST_URI', 'DOCUMENT_URI', 'DOCUMENT_ROOT', 'SERVER_PROTOCOL', 'GATEWAY_INTERFACE', 'SERVER_SOFTWARE', 'REMOTE_ADDR', 'REMOTE_PORT', 'SERVER_ADDR', 'SERVER_PORT', 'SERVER_NAME', 'REDIRECT_STATUS'};
print $output;
```

And here is the output I get:

```
$ git clone http://git.domain.com/1.git
Cloning into '1'...
fatal: http://git.domain.com/1.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

Apparently, I did run `git update-server-info`. Because for example I can clone this repository without `git-http-backend`:

```
server {
    server_name   git.domain.com;
    root   /home/yuri/git;
}
```

And here is the data I get in `1.txt`:

```
Status: 404 Not Found^M
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT^M
Pragma: no-cache^M
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate^M
^M
$VAR1 = {
          'SERVER_NAME' => 'git.domain.com',
          'SCRIPT_NAME' => '/1.git/info/refs',
          'CONTENT_LENGTH' => '',
          'REQUEST_METHOD' => 'GET',
          'SERVER_SOFTWARE' => 'nginx/0.7.67',
          'REMOTE_PORT' => '53908',
          'QUERY_STRING' => 'service=git-upload-pack',
          'SERVER_PORT' => '80',
          'REDIRECT_STATUS' => '200',
          'REMOTE_ADDR' => 'x.x.x.x',
          'CONTENT_TYPE' => '',
          'SERVER_PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP/1.1',
          'DOCUMENT_URI' => '/1.git/info/refs',
          'REQUEST_URI' => '/1.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack',
          'GATEWAY_INTERFACE' => 'CGI/1.1',
          'SERVER_ADDR' => 'x.x.x.x',
          'DOCUMENT_ROOT' => '/home/yuri/git'
        };
```

I'm running `Debian squeeze`, `fcgiwrap-1.0`, `git-1.7.2.5`, `nginx-0.7.67`.

**UPD** I would be grateful if someone could at least provide me with the output of my script under apache?

---

On a side note, this version of fcgiwrap ignores `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `SCRIPT_NAME` are concatenated and split back again into the script name and `PATH_INFO`. But the first `fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT` must point to the right location, otherwise `fcgiwrap` wouldn't find the script to be launched for some reason. That is, this doesn't work:

```
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   $document_root;   # /usr/local/nginx/html
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
```

But this works:

```
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   $document_root;   # /usr/local/nginx/html
```

That is the reason behind slightly obscure `nginx` configuration:

```
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/lib/git-core;
        ...
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
```

But there are some setups when it works...

Comment: Aside, you have your host name visible in the top `server_name`.

Comment: Oh, thanks for your remark :) though, it's password-protected...

Comment: @Lekensteyn, I can't comment your answer, so... First off, I have `fcgiwrap-1.0-1+squeeze1` and it ignores `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. You can see it by inspecting commit history of [v1.0.1](https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap/commits/v1.0.1) and [v1.0.2](https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap/commits/v1.0.2). Anyway, I've checked it with the following [nginx config](http://sprunge.us/DETg?nginx) and the following [test script](http://sprunge.us/QYUB?perl).

Comment: I decided to make order of fastcgi_param a [separate question](http://serverfault.com/questions/512028/nginx-fcgiwrap-how-come-order-of-fastcgi-param-matters).

Comment: I am using a development version containing [a patch for a way to restrict executable files](https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap/commit/3a94c2) on Wheezy. I knew the squeeze one was buggy, so I never bothered trying that one. Hey, it is a single executable anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it didn't work was that `PATH_INFO` wasn't set correctly. Since "`DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `SCRIPT_NAME` are concatenated and split back again into the script name and `PATH_INFO`". This is the configuration that works:

```
server {
    server_name   domain.com;
    root   /home/yuri/git;
    access_log   /var/log/nginx/domain.com-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/domain.com-error.log;

    location / {
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

        fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT   /usr/lib/git-core;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME   /git-http-backend$fastcgi_script_name;
        include   fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param   GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL   "";
        fastcgi_param   GIT_PROJECT_ROOT   /home/yuri/git;
    }
}
```

Then you can clone repositories like this:

```
git clone http://domain.com/1.git
```

where `1.git` is located in `/home/yuri/git`.

Answer (score 1):

`DOCUMENT_ROOT` + `SCRIPT_NAME` cannot be combined with `PATH_INFO`. Use an absolute `SCRIPT_FILENAME` instead (since your `git-http-backend` program is located out of your document root).

As a debugging hint, to test whether smart HTTP works, look at your access logs.

The following configuration is tested on Debian 7.0 Wheezy:

```
# based on http-backend.c from git v1.8.2.1, service_cmd
location ~ "^/[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+/(git-(receive|upload)-pack|HEAD|info/refs|objects/(info/(http-)?alternates|packs)|[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38}|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx))$" {
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/yuri/git;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgi-wrap.sock;
}
```

Adding options like `GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL` is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Still doesn't work, here are the [nginx config](http://sprunge.us/idBA), [shell output](http://sprunge.us/VXHR) and [perl-script output](http://sprunge.us/OAcF). By the way, PATH_INFO doesn't get passed, as opposed to PATH_INFO2 e.g. Could you tell what you're getting (when it works, of course)?

Comment: @x-yuri, since it seems a personal server, can you upgrade from Squeeze to Wheezy to make your software more up-to-date? What does `fastcgi_params` contain? Mine is at http://fpaste.org/15991/

Comment: Actually it's a production server :) And well I can install wheezy on my PC, but that would take time. And I'd be grateful if you'd tell what environment of CGI process is when it works. Because that's what I guess is causing the problems. My `fastcgi_params` is [like this](http://sprunge.us/dgMH).

Comment: @x-yuri You mentioned that `SCRIPT_FILENAME` gets ignored with your fcgiwrap version. I strongly recommend you upgrading `fcgiwrap` to a more recent version where this is fixed if you are unable to upgrade to Wheezy. This also holds for production environments.

Comment: Lekensteyn: I just tested your config on a vanilla wheezy installation and it worked after two minor changes:

- changed /var/run/fcgi-wrap.sock to /var/run/fcgiwrap.socket (the default on wheezy)
- installed git 1.8.x from wheezy-backports. git 1.7 refused to work for some reason.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LucaG. I have actually compiled fcgiwrap from source because the one in Wheezy was insufficient, that's why your paths may be different than mine. If you take fcgiwrap from jessie or sid (1.1.0-1), then you also have a `-p` option to restrict the allowed programs (see https://github.com/gnosek/fcgiwrap/pull/12 for details) which is why I compiled it manually.